# Does an Ipad simulator exist to test websites locally

Tags: html, ipad

I've been given a project to make a website that is functional on the desktop and ipad. This is great but I don't own an ipad.

Is there any-sort of simulation I can use to test my local website to see its functionality on an ipad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See:

- [Test a website on an iPad](http://osxdaily.com/2010/09/28/test-a-website-on-an-ipad/)
- [How Does your Website Look on an iPad (without having one)?](http://www.labnol.org/internet/test-websites-on-ipad/13368/)
- [Using Safari for iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch Website Testing](http://www.labnol.org/internet/test-websites-on-ipad/13368/)

Alternatively, you can also register for a free developer ID and download xCode. Use the iOS simulator included to simulate any kind of iOS devices. Here is a screenshot of an iPhone 5 displaying google's search page on my MAC.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is really simulating how the website would run on an ipad, only how it would 'look' under the ipads screen resolution. What I'm trying to test is the html5 video .load() function which I know doesn't work on ipad (I'm trying to make a hack to allow it). Yet on the simulators you described the html5 .load() fucntion works

Comment: How can I run the ipad simulator in xcode without having to create an app?

Comment: Then, you may prefer the iOS simulator. Note however that the look will not feel the same if you don't have a retina display macbook pro. It will also be larger. If you give me the address of the website, I can post a picture of your website in an iPad.

Comment: @JamieFearon Open Xcode. Got to `Xcode` menu => `Open developer tool` => `iOS Simulator`. Once the simulator is loaded, start safari in the simulator and browse the web. You don't need to create any application for that. If you don't want to open xCode, the simulator is located in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/D‌​eveloper/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app

Comment: if your site uses a session cookie or any cookie for that matter - forget this

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. You must install Xcode and then run the iPad simulator (like if you where testing your app) and go to the web browser (safari) and type the address of your website.

Comment: I have xcode. Please could you explain how I can run the iPad simulator without having to create a basic app. I just want to test my website located in hdocs

Comment: @JamieFearon Open Xcode. Got to Xcode menu => Open developer tool => iOS Simulator. Once the simulator is loaded, start safari in the simulator and browse the web. You don't need to create any application for that. If you don't want to open xCode, the simulator is located in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app`

Comment: This option is not on my xcode Version 4.1 is this a new option?

Comment: I am using Xcode version 4.6.1 ; Maybe you need to upgrade. I don't remember how it was before.

Comment: Cool, thanks I will upgrade an try.